# How creating dynamic http response from a component using HttpResponse or something else

Tags: asp.net

I've developed a component which processes online payments. At a specific point the user must be redirected to the selected acquirer web site for authentication. The acquirer itself suggests that there should be a web page which does it. Something such as the following,

```
<!--TakeOff.aspx-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>@</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Go() {
            form1.submit();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="Go();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" action="https://acquirer/...">
    <div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="MID" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="Amount" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="ResNum" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="RedirectURL" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This page redirects the user and posts required arguments to the acquirer’s web site. Prior to this page there is another page with a payment button (for example). In the click event of the payment button my component is instantiated and required calculation is done. Something such as the following,

```
protected void btnPayment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var paymentProcessor = new NS.PaymentProcessor(/*required arguments*/);
        /*...*/
        NS.Result result = paymentProcessor.Calc();

        Session.Add("PaymentProcessResult", result);
        Response.Redirect("TakeOff.aspx");
    }
    catch (Exception p)
    {
        throw p;
    }
}
```

What I’m going to do is to generate [TakeOff.aspx] page at run-time by the payment processor component instead of having static page (I mean aspx pages that are generated during development phase). The reason why is that we may have different acquirers and each acquirer requires its own arguments to be posted. So if the payment processor component generates aspx or even html pages at run-time we do not need recompile and redeploy the web application.

My problem is that I do not know how to generate aspx pages at run-time. I’m not an ASP.NET guru and all efforts that I’ve made using HttpResponse were in vain as the original page does not transfer the control to the generated page.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generating an aspx page is not a good way to solve this problem. I think I would do it this way:

In your C# code somewhere define the form values that each acquirer expects. Something like:

```
public string GenerateForm()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    Dictionary<string, string> inputs = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    // Maybe this comes from a database instead?
    switch (Request["acquirer"])
    {
        // Add more here
        case "acquirer1":
            inputs = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "MID", "SOMETHING" },
                { "Amount", "SOMETHING" }
                // ...
            };
            break;
    }

    // Make each input
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> input in inputs)
    {
        sb.Append(
            "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + input.Key + "\" value=\"" + input.Value + "\" />"
        );
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Then just take this generated HTML and insert it into your form.

Comment: Dear Caleb,
Thanks a lot for your attention and the solution you’ve provided,

Would you please tell me why generating aspx or html pages at run-time is not a good practice? Please consider that it may be possible to generate an html page (using HttpResponse or other component) containing the form and hidden fields and that html page which dynamically is created and outputted to the client and there the form submits and everything seems to be OK. The problem is that control from the original page is not transfer to generated html page. Do you have any idea? (Again thanks a lot)